# Location of executable files in Linux

Tags: linux, root

Besides /bin and /sbin/, which are the other directories in Linux where executable files are stored? I am aware the whereis command is used to find location of the files, but I can't find any other directory besides these two.

Comment: *"I can't find any other directory..."* -- Apparently you're not aware of the [PATH environment variable](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html).

Comment: Yes, I am, I did check the value of the PATH variable. I got the following value -
`/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Answer (score 2):

Please note that executables can also be located in /opt/*/bin and in /opt/*/sbin. Further, there are often in /usr/libexec also.

Answer (score 1):

Some executables files are stored in `/usr/bin` (and `/usr/sbin`). This is usually installed scripts and apps. You should store your own scripts in `/usr/local/bin` if you want to execute them from the whole system (or `/usr/local/sbin`). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: Note that you *can* execute from virtually any location, e.g. Documents, as long as the x bit is set and you have access.